# safely storing untrusted files on a trusted machine

Tags: malware, linux, ubuntu

given a collection of files (text and binary) that are likely to have been modified by a resourceful and motivated adversary in a targeted attack, is there a security risk to copying that collection of files to a trusted linux machine ? if there is a risk, can it be mitigated by changing settings ?

this is currently running ubuntu 21.10 but other mainstream linux distributions are also of interest. some examples of vectors that i'm worried about are the [gnome thumbnailer](https://gubins.lv/posts/thumbnailer/), nautilus, [gnome tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) and mlocate, ie complex processes that scan through all files that almost certainly have exploits

i'm not worried (in this question) about accidentally manually clicking/viewing/running one of the files

my threat model is a (non-profit) side project by 1-2 members of a successful for-profit hacking group, ie sub-APT but a single zero-day is conceivable

Comment: Encrypt the files before copying?

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is in vectors manifesting in large external codebases (like GNOME), just copy your suspicious files into a "bare" linux machine (something light without heaps of preinstalled software such as debian or arch). Also, would recommend putting them into a potentially vulnerable system in a VM and analyzing the malware to extract the vuln used; maybe you'll uncover a 0day.

The risk to your machine *could* be stemmed through setting changes however if the vulnerability in use is unknown, so are the settings to change. The safest way is to just not use complex GUI software and use heavily used and tested system utilities (`ls`, `cat`, etc). Alternatively, you could also use more obscure (still popular though) file managers like `ranger` or `nnn`, as your adversary is unlikely to have found a vuln that spans those specific pieces of software (if they believe you aren't using them).

Ultimately, the best way to view the files, if you believe they are compromised, is in a virtual machine.

Comment: Using `cat` on its own is a little risky because it opens up the very real possibility of terminal exploits, since `cat` does not sanitize output. What you could do instead is use `cat -v` which removes control characters (or rather, makes them visible).

Comment: [VM escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine_escape) are common, so i'd really have to investigate one VM in particular to decide if i feel it offers meaningful security. can you suggest a particular (linux-based, ideally) VM that's reasonably likely to protect the host machine ?

that said, your point about being able to omit GNOME and run bare bones on the VM is a great point